# Panel items not separating

Tags: c#

This is for windows deskop, not asp.net. I have a panel and I am adding items to it. Right now the items are showing up, but on top of each other. I want them to be spaced by a blank line. What am I doing wrong?

```
string[] stng = { "1", "2" };
foreach (string stng123 in stng)
{
    Panel entryPanel = new Panel();
    Label lbInfo = new Label();
    lbInfo.AutoSize = true;
    lbInfo.Text = "stng123 + Environment.NewLine + "testing";

    Button delButton = new Button();
    delButton.Text = "Delete";
    delButton.Location = new Point(120, 0);
    delButton.Click += (s, e) => { panel1.Controls.Remove(entryPanel); };

    panel1.Controls.Add(entryPanel);
    entryPanel.Controls.Add(lbInfo);
    entryPanel.Controls.Add(delButton);
    entryPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 240, 0);
}
panel1.Height = (panel1.Controls.Count) + 88;
```

Comment: lbInfo.Text = "stng123" + Environment.NewLine + "testing";

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Right now, your code creates two child panels (entryPanel), both at location 0,0 in a single parent panel (panel1). Just change the location of one of the two child panels...

Comment: When I create the panel they are placed on top of each other. I want each entryPanel to be added to the panel one under another, basically a list. I tried adding a location to each entryPanel but it moved did not move anything.

Comment: For Vertical stacking set your entryPanel.Dock=Top